# Sharing Data Between Android Apps By The Same Developer

Tags: android

We have a requirement to share some very simple data between Android apps, the data will basically just be a string but we want to ensure it's only shared between apps signed by us. The sharing of the data also needs to be programmatic i.e. without user interaction to initiate the sharing.

The issue we have with many of the data sharing methods we've found is that they imply the data is owned by one particular app which then makes it available to other apps. The data we need to share could be generated by any app so it doesn't have a natural owner.

Our ideal solution would be something similar to the Keychain on iOS where any app can write the data and any app can easily check if the data has already been written.

We have seen some solutions that involve setting a shared User ID for the apps but this appears to be deprecated in Android and also one of our apps is already in the store so the ID cannot now be changed.

Is anyone aware of any possible solutions on Android for this usecase?

Comment: Why not have a common Database of some kind that you can then access via some API?

Comment: We need the data to be stored on the device so we'd still need a shared location on the device to store the database and be sure only apps signed by us can access it.

Comment: Add a content provider to every app which can deliver the requested info.

Comment: In that case every app would need to know about every other apps content provider and whenever the data changes you'd need to have a process for updating them all. This also comes back to data ownership problem, if the content providers started giving different results you'd have no way to know which is correct. All of which seems like a very complicated way to share a string when we basically just need some shared storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service with AIDL to share whatever you need between apps:

> The Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL) is similar to other
> IDLs: it lets you define the programming interface that both the
> client and service agree upon in order to communicate with each other
> using interprocess communication (IPC).

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl

You may also need to define a query for Android 11 (API level 30)

```
<manifest package="com.example.game">
  <queries>
    <!-- Specific apps you interact with, eg: -->
    <package android:name="com.example.service" />
  </queries>
  ...
</manifest>
```

---

To share a file securely, the same application-signature may be required:

> Code/data sharing through permissions: Android provides
> signature-based permissions enforcement, so that an app can expose
> functionality to another app that is signed with a specified
> certificate. By signing multiple APKs with the same certificate and
> using signature-based permissions checks, your apps can share code and
> data in a secure manner.

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#considerations

Then you can use ContentProvider or SharedPrefs with PackageContext